# Modification needed in python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to sort a file by last column (ascending) and grep the top hundred lines. The code is:

```
import sys
from operator import itemgetter
file_name = sys.argv[1]
with open(file_name) as file:
    file_contents = file.read()
lines = file_contents.split("\n")[1:-1] 
data = [(i, float(line.split()[-1])) for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1))
print lines[sorted_data[0]]
```

File format:

```
1                        ddddd     346700    T        ADD      798   0.002934       0.2829       0.7
1                         dddd     943567    A        ADD      798   -0.02574       -1.496       0.1
```

This code returns the error:

```
error 
list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: the first and the last file line are ignored, hope that's ok

Answer (score 1):

Your sorted_data is a list of tuples with the first number being the line number in the lines variable. Your code errors because you are trying to pass a tuple instead of an integer into your lines variable when you print. To get the relevant lines in the lines variable you can use a list comprehension:

```
results = [lines[idx] for idx, v in sorted_data]
print(results[:100])
```

Comment: This is giving me a list as output

Comment: It's a sorted list of the rows you want. The final format is up to you.

Comment: ok how can i print just sorted top 100 lines and  store them in a separate file. what i want to do is open file and sort it by last column and then grep top 100 sorted lines in a separate file